# App Already Bootstrapped with this Element when using ng-include

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-include

I want to create a custom panel for controlling different files. I am trying to use ng-include or a directive but both of them throw this error: "App Already Bootstrapped with this Element"

What I am trying to do is.

Template: presentationControls.html

```
<input class="btn-control" type="image" src="../../img/control_icons/fullscreen-icon.png" />
<input class="btn-control" type="image" src="../../img/control_icons/prev-icon.png" ng-click="sendControlCommand('{PGUP}')" />
<input class="btn-control" type="image" src="../../img/control_icons/next-icon.png" ng-click="sendControlCommand('{PGDN}')" />
<input class="btn-control" type="image" src="../../img/control_icons/close-icon.png" ng-click="closeFile(file.id)" />
```

In my index.html

```
<div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>

        <div class="col-sm-8 center-block text-center">
            <div class="btn-group" ng-show="true" ng-include="'..\..\views\partials\presentationControl.html'"></div>
        </div>

</div>
```

And I also tried making my own directive which would work if I included the template as template: '...' but not when using templateUrl

```
myApp.directive("controlsPanel", [function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            templateUrl: '..\..\views\partials\presentationControl.html',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {}
        }
    }]);
```

I tried both creating it as attribute or element to see if it had something to do with it.

I am not using the angular.bootstrap and I am only declaring ng-app="..." once so that is not the reason :( I have no idea how to solve this. Please any help is welcome :)

Thanks!!